# pexpect need to use pipe without starting the bash shell since the bash shell does not understand the command

Tags: python, bash, pexpect

I want to do something likethis using pexpect

```
echild = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash -c "sysinfo -v | grep "SCM"')
fout = file('/home/kiva/release_file.txt' , 'w+')
child.logfile = fout
```

The problem is that I want the out of that command into a textfile but I have to start a shell since we cannot use pipe in spawn(). The bash shell does not understand sysinfo -v and complains about it.

Do you guys have any idea or know of a way in which I can get the desired output into the file without opening the bash terminal? I can solve the issue by just using the spawn() method without grepping it but I want the exact match and hence grep is necessary.

Thank you

Comment: You appear to be missing a double-quote in there somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

From your short example I do not see why you specifically need to use pexpect to achieve this. I would go for the `Popen`way. Here's a link that might prove useful:

[Replacing shell pipeline - Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline)